# which country’s requirements for higher license?

Tags: easa-regulations

If I have a license registered in country A and want to add a higher license with a flight school in country B (both countries are in EASA), which country’s rules apply for requirements for the higher license? Let’s say, country A requires 10 more hours of something for the higher license, does that also apply if the higher license is done in country B?